# Windows create a VPN connection out of a local proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy

I'm on Windows 11. I have some proxy applications to bypass censorship, for example V2ray or tunneling via Putty SSH. All these apps make a http or socks5 proxy 127.0.0.1 with a custom listening port.

So I can directly modify the system proxy settings and apply 127.0.0.1:port which makes most programs work.

The problem is that some programs are set to make connection without proxy and they ignore Window's proxy settings.
For example Firefox default network settings is set to make direct connection. So setting up a proxy on Windows won't make a difference. Another example is Microsoft Store. This app doesn't respect proxy settings and unlike Firefox there's no way to make it use proxy.

However, VPN apps all make the routing on a deeper level which Firefox or Store can't detect.

So is it possible on Windows that I somehow convert my working local proxy into a VPN connection? Hopefully is there an program for that?

On a side note, I have successfully done this on Android. I have setup `Connectbot` to make a SSH tunnel with port forwarding then I used `AndProxy` which makes that portforward into a VPN connection. `AndProxy` has a bypass application mode which allows me to bypass `Connectbot` so that the new VPN connection doesn't interrupt my main proxy source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had your problem and solved it. You can use NekoRay at https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray which has a VPN mode.
You can setup your socks proxy in NekoRay and then turn on VPN mode so it routes all the traffic of Microsoft Store and other apps from the proxy.

Comment: Yes NekoRay does that but only for its own generated proxy.  For example if I make an SSH tunnel via Putty, I can't make a VPN connection with NekoRay. NekoRay only supports V2ray subscriptions.

Comment: You can add your Putty generated 127.0.0.1:port Socks5 proxy in a new profile in NekoRay. NekoRay is not only for V2Ray subscriptions. I'm using the mentioned configuration right now without a problem.

Comment: Wow didn't know that. Thanks a lot! I'll mark it as solved :)

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: Nice Answer. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called `proxycap` which solves the problem. It doesn't create a VPN connection, but it binds all programs to use your proxy. It doesn't change the connections made before turning it on. So you can first start your main proxy source, then you can turn `proxycap` on. It allows program-based routing (instead of all programs) as well.

https://www.proxycap.com/